# Android no asigna variable recibida en JSON

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json

Al mandar llamar a mi web service, este me devuelve una cadena JSON con un solo resultado, pero cuando quiero asignar el resultado a una variable no se asigna y me marca como null. Cabe destacar que el web service funciona correctamente.

Este dato se encuentra como "date" en la base de datos.

Cadena JSON que se devuelve:

```
[{"0":"2020-11-18","fechaEntrada":"2020-11-18"}]
```

Variable local en Android:

```
private String entrada;
```

Parseo de JSON:

```
private void fecha_entrada(String URL){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            //lectura y asignación de datos
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    entrada = jsonObject.getString("fechaEntrada");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No es posible recuperar la información, favor de contactar a TI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay Registros", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            plantilla_default();
        }
    });

    //Instancia
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}
```

Llamada de método:

```
fecha_entrada("http://192.168.0.9/APPRH/estadisticas/fecha_entrada.php");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FechaEntrada: "+ entrada, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Puedes loggear la variable `response`para ver que hay en ella? y tambien loggea `response.getJSONObject(i)`

Comment: @AndresGardiol, al loggear: response.getJSONObject(i) me arroja la cadena JSON

`2021-02-17 13:15:59.139 31950-31950/com.example.login_apprh V/{"0":"2020-11-18","fechaEntrada":"2020-11-18"}: Entrada: 2020-11-18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El problema se debe a que el proceso de obtención del valor al realizar la petición es asíncrono**, por lo tanto al tratar de mostrar el valor mediante el Toast sería un poco difícil

```
fecha_entrada("http://192.168.0.9/APPRH/estadisticas/fecha_entrada.php");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FechaEntrada: "+ entrada, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Lo ideal es obtener el valor dentro del método `onResponse()` de la petición `Volley`:

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            //lectura y asignación de datos
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    entrada = jsonObject.getString("fechaEntrada");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No es posible recuperar la información, favor de contactar a TI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
      
            //Muestra valor de variable entrada.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FechaEntrada: "+ entrada, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

---

También puedes realizarlo mediante una interfaz:

```
private void fecha_entrada(final VolleyCallback callback, String URL){

@Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            ...
            ...
            ...
            callback.onSuccess(entrada);
        }
}
```

Define la interfaz

```
public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(String result);
}
```

De esta forma realizarías la petición y mostrarías su valor

```
fecha_entrada(new VolleyCallback(){
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(String result){
                 entrada = result;
                //Muestra valor de variable entrada.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FechaEntrada: "+ entrada, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }, "http://192.168.0.9/APPRH/estadisticas/fecha_entrada.php");
```

Revisa este ejemplo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738660/return-json-from-custom-volleycallback-interface-to-calling-method